# How to use one directive in multiple controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers the **'first-controller'**, **'second-controller'** and the one directive **'executeOnEsc'**.

I need to "share" this directive between these two controllers: the directive  should call the *$scope.clear* function in **scope 1** and change the variable *someVar* in **scope 2**.

Right now, as you can see in the code snippet, the directive produces the error: scope.clear is not a function.

And that's make sense, because directive runs two times: first in *scope 1* and afterwards in *scope 2*, which doesn't have the *'clear'* function.

What is the solution for this situation? I can make two different directives, but that's no the best solution.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('first-controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 'Scope 1 | Press ESC Key';
  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.value = 'Scope 1 value changed!';
  }
});

app.controller('second-controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.someVar = 'Scope 2 | Press ESC Key';
});

app.directive('executeOnEsc', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope) {
      return $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.which === 27) {
          return scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.someVar = 'Scope 2 value changed!';
            scope.clear();
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.someDiv {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.second {
  background-color: #3498db;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="first-controller">
    <div class="someDiv" execute-on-esc>
      <p>{{ value }}
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second" ng-controller="second-controller" execute-on-esc>
    <p>{{ someVar }}
      <p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The best solution would be add a callback handler to the attribute like `execute-on-esc="yourCallback"`. Then you could define the callback in each of your controllers like `$scope.yourCallback = function(){}`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create 2 different directive you just need to add clear function in the second controller  too

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('first-controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 'Scope 1 | Press ESC Key';
  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.value = 'Scope 1 value changed!';
  }
});

app.controller('second-controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.someVar = 'Scope 2 | Press ESC Key';
  $scope.clear = function() 
  {
      $scope.someVar = ' Scope 2 value changed!';
  }
});

app.directive('executeOnEsc', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope) {
      return $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.which === 27) {
          return scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.someVar = 'Scope 2 value changed!';
            scope.clear();
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.someDiv {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.second {
  background-color: #3498db;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="first-controller">
    <div class="someDiv" execute-on-esc>
      <p>{{ value }}
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second" ng-controller="second-controller" execute-on-esc>
    <p>{{ someVar }}
      <p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use one directive in multipal controller, then the you can write it in **route.js** file at bottom.
for Exp.

```
angular
 .module('myapp')
 .config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    '$httpProvider',

    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            controller: 'homeController',
            templateUrl: 'templates/home_page.html'
        })

    }
    ]).directive('executeOnEsc', function($document) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope) {
          return $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
            if (event.which === 27) {
              return scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.someVar = 'Scope 2 value changed!';
                scope.clear();
              });
            }
          });
        }
      };
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Not the best solution, but it works:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('first-controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 'Scope 1 | Press ESC Key';
  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.value = 'Scope 1 value changed!';
  }
});

app.controller('second-controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.someVar = 'Scope 2 | Press ESC Key';
  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.someVar = ' Scope 2 value changed!';
  }
});

app.directive('executeOnEsc', function($document) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope) {
      return $document.bind('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.which === 27) {
          return scope.$apply(function() {
            if (typeof scope.clear === 'function') {
              scope.clear();
            } else {
              scope.someVar = 'Scope 2 value changed!';
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.someDiv {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.second {
  background-color: #3498db;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="first-controller">
    <div class="someDiv" execute-on-esc>
      <p>{{ value }}
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second" ng-controller="second-controller" execute-on-esc>
    <p>{{ someVar }}
      <p>
  </div>
</section>
```